# How to add data from async method in singleton in Startup.cs in net.core 3.0?

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-3.0

I'm trying to get async data from HttpClient and add this data as singleton at ConfigureServices in Startup.cs

```
public static class SolDataFill
{
    static HttpClient Client;

    static SolDataFill()
    {
        Client = new HttpClient();
    }

    public static async Task<SolData> GetData(AppSettings option)
    {
        var ulr = string.Format(option.MarsWheaterURL, option.DemoKey);
        var httpResponse = await Client.GetAsync(ulr);

        var stringResponse = await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        var wheather = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SolData>(stringResponse);
        return wheather;
    }
}
```

**Startup.cs**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.Configure<AppSettings>(Configuration);
    var settings = Configuration.GetSection("NasaHttp") as AppSettings;
    var sData = await SolDataFill.GetData(settings);
    services.AddSingleton<SolData>(sData);
}
```

There is an error: it's possible to use await with async only. How to add data from async method to singleton?

Comment: Have you tried `var sData = SolDataFill.GetData(settings).Result;`?

Comment: You can just run this method synchronously using `GetAwaiter().GetResult()`

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you should consider to rework your `SolDataFill` to end up as a DataService instead of adding everything to the DI container.

Then everybody who needs the data can query for it. (This is why I have added the cache here to not always do a request)

```
public class SolDataFill
{
    private readonly HttpClient _client;
    private readonly AppSettings _appSettings;
    private readonly ILogger _logger;
    
    private static SolData cache;
    
    public SolDataFill(HttpClient client, AppSettings options, ILogger<SolDataFill> logger)
    {
        _client = client;
        _appSettings = options;
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public async Task<SolData> GetDataAsync()
    {
        if(cache == null)
        {
            var ulr = string.Format(_appSettings.MarsWheaterURL, _appSettings.DemoKey);
            _logger.LogInformation(ulr);
            var httpResponse = await _client.GetAsync(ulr);
            if(httpResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                _logger.LogInformation("{0}", httpResponse.StatusCode);
                var stringResponse = await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                cache = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SolData>(stringResponse);
                return cache;
            }
            else
            {
                _logger.LogInformation("{0}", httpResponse.StatusCode);
            }
        }
        return cache;
    }
}
```

[Full example can be found here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/GzqEUn)

Like written in the comments of your question its very simple to run a async method synchronous by just `GetAwaiter().GetResult()`. But in my optinion everytime I see this code I personally think there is a code smell hidden which can be refactored.